# Redirect from 2 buttons to the same page

Tags: php, html

I am kinda lost at how to Redirect from 2 buttons to the same page but to show both website link or demo link when the buttons are clicked on and been Redirected.

So I got those buttons that works fine

```html
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo $row["siteurl"]; ?>pages/red.php?url=<?php echo $sitez['id']; ?>/<?php echo $sitez['Website']; ?>" role="button"><strong>Go to <?php echo $sitez["name"]; ?></strong></a>

<a class="btn btn-success"  href="<?php echo $row["siteurl"]; ?>pages/red.php?url=<?php echo $sitez['id']; ?>/<?php echo $sitez['demo']; ?>/" role="button"><strong>Check <?php echo $sitez["name"]; ?> Demo Link</strong></a></center>
```

This is where I get them to Redirect, so I need this to show either demo or website link

```js
    setInterval(function() {
                var div = document.querySelector("#timer");
                var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
                div.textContent = count;
                if (count <= 0) {
                    window.location.replace("<?php echo $usez['Website']; ?>");
                }
            }, 3000);
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET['urlz'])) {
 $urlz = ($_GET['urlz']); 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE id='$urlz' AND approved='1' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
  if( $result )  
  while($usez = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>       
<strong>You are being redirected to an external site.</strong>

You will be redirected to <?php echo $usez['name']; ?> 

You are going to <?php echo $usez['Website']; ?> 


 like to show demo here also but when only demo is clicked  <?php echo $usez['demo']; ?> 


 in <a id="timer">30</a> Seconds 

<strong>Please note that <?php echo $row['title']; ?> is not responsible for the content of the external site.</strong>
           </tr>                    
                 </table>  
                  </div>
              </div>
</div>    
   <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can refine your link as:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo $row["siteurl"].'pages/red.php?url='.$sitez['id'].'\'.$sitez["Website"]; ?>" role="button"><strong>Go to <?php echo $sitez["name"]; ?></strong></a>
```

you may also use `<?=$site['url'].'xyz'.$otherVarible?>`
it does the same as `<? php echo""; ?>`

If you want a distinction for the source button on the backend, like the user clicked demo button or website button, you can always pass an extra GET parameter, making it two different links routing to same path as:

```
www.example.com/red.php?isDemo=1  // for demo website
www.example.com/red.php?isDemo=0  // for actual website
```

then you may check it on the backend as:

```
if (isset($_GET['isDemo']) && $_GET['isDemo'] == 1)
```

Comment: Hi akhill  how would that work as i am already using $_GET in details  page and that is where i got those 2 buttons going from and how it work in javascript? as this is confessing  me sorry  also how would 1 and 0 display the link?? on the page when the website url will still show anyway?

Comment: @Wourease I am not sure which one is your details page but, this may help you in understanding $_GET https://teamtreehouse.com/community/passing-a-get-variable-through-a-link-with-php-2    0, 1 are just conditional checks to identify whether the user clicked demo button or website button. And javascript... that would be complex as you are redirecting... as soon as the new page will load, you will lose the frontend js data of the previous page